# What should be the Podspec file for using local .xcframework in React Native library?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, react-native-ios, podspec, xcframework

I created a React Native library that is a wrapper for using the native iOS framework in the React Native Projects. Earlier I was using **.framework** & it was working fine. Now I am facing an issue in using this library with **.xcframework** instead of **.framework**.

I added this library as a dependency to the project & then on running `pod install` getting the below error:

**[!] [Xcodeproj] Generated duplicate UUIDs:**

When I opened the project & try to build it, it builds successfully for the device but fails on the simulator.

Below is the Podspec file that I am using in the library project:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "react-native-myLibrary"
  s.version      = "1.0.0"
  s.summary      = "react-native-myLibrary"
  s.description  = <<-DESC
                    react-native-myLibrary
                   DESC
  
  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal"
  s.license      = "MIT"
  s.author       = { "author" => "author@domain.cn" }
  s.platform     = :ios, "10.0"
  s.source       = { :http => 'file:' + __dir__ + '/' }

  s.source_files = "**/*.{h,m,swift}"
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'MyLibrary.xcframework'

  s.dependency "React"
end
```

On searching for the solution I found that this error is caused by `s.source_files = "**/*.{h,m,swift}"`. So, I commented this line & run `pod install` again. The error was gone but no dependency is being added to the Project target. Can anyone provide me the **Podspec** file to use for local **.xcframework** in React Native Library. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm also facing similar issue.

Comment: Hey Ankur, how do you generate xcframework file using react-native?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue using:

```
s.source_files = "ios/*.{h,m,swift}"
s.vendored_frameworks = 'ios/Frameworks/MyLibrary.xcframework'
```

& also by updating the Framework Search Paths from the Build Settings to **$(inherited)**.

Comment: [!] Unable to install vendored xcframework `MyLibrary` for Pod `demo-sdk-react-native`, because it contains both static and dynamic frameworks.

Any idea about this error ??

Comment: @MehulAkoliya I am facing the same error. Were you able to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```rb
s.preserve_paths =  'MyFraemwork.xcframework/*'
s.source_files = 'MyFraemwork.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/PicUPSDKv3.framework/Headers/*.{h,m,swift}'
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. No dependency is added to the Target.

Comment: Go to the **Pods** project, click Pods-MyTarget then go to Build Phases and look at the Dependencies. Do you see your XCFramework there? (your target links with Pods-MyTarget)

Comment: I don't see MyLibrary.xcframework there. But it has the **react-native-myLibrary(Pods)** added in the Dependencies.